# Confusion about the evaluation of Disjunction

Tags: logic

At junior school, I was taught to understanding disjunction by using the concept of union, for example, $(x\gt 3) \vee (x \gt 10)$, to evaluate this expression, simply evaluate to $\{ x|x\gt3 \vee x\gt10 \}$, $x\gt3$ is dominant,so finally, the expression evaluates to $x\gt3$.The second example, $(x\gt0) \vee (x\lt0)$,by using the same method in example 1, I get $x\ne0$.

If I want to use the definition of disjunction, according to the definition of disjunction, the disjunction is true if and only if at least one of disjuncts is true, I get confused to evaluate the sentence. In example 1,$(x\gt 3) \vee (x \gt 10)$ is true if $(x\gt 3) $ is true or $(x \gt 10)$ is true,or both are true. Then how can I get $x\gt3 $? 
This confuses me most when disjuncts are not $x\gt3$ ,but A ,B.
Thanks

Comment: I'm really not sure what they were teaching you in junior school. It's true that $\{x:x>3\}\cup\{x:x>10\}=\{x:x>3\}$, but that isn't about disjunction; it's because $x>10\Rightarrow x>3$. And $P\vee Q$ doesn't "evalueate" to either $P$ or $Q$, it's just either true or false.

Comment: @MaliceVidrine I'm not sure why you would say this is unrelated to disjunction. In general, $\{x\mid P(x)\}\cup\{x\mid Q(x)\}=\{x\mid P(x)\lor Q(x)\}$. That $P(x)\lor Q(x)\iff P(x)$ in this case seems like a separable concern. If $P$ and $Q$ have free variables then $P\lor Q$ does not "evaluate to" (better, is not interpreted as) true or false. In fact, the usual interpretation of $P\lor Q$ assuming they both have at most $x$ free is exactly the first comprehension I mentioned (with $x$ implicitly restricted to the domain of the interpretation).

Comment: @DerekElkins - I wasn't saying that union is unrelated to disjunction. I was saying that the union can be rewritten as only one of its components is not itself a property of disjunction; it is not something one will generally find to be the case.

Comment: (And while it's clear to me that the fact that $P\Leftrightarrow P\vee Q$ is a separable issue from how to interpret disjunction, it's not obvious to me that the OP understands that.)

Comment: Re: the specific question: one of the key properties of disjunction is that from $P\vee Q$ and $P\implies Q$ we can deduce $Q$. Formally, we prove this by cases: if $P\vee Q$ is true, then either $P$ is true - in which case $Q$ is also true since $P\implies Q$ - or $Q$ is true; either way, $Q$ is true. In your example, $P$ is $x>10$ and $Q$ is $x>3$: $P\vee Q$ is equivalent to $Q$. Does this make sense? (Notice that this patterns exactly the explanation of why $\{x:x>3\}\cup\{x:x>10\}=\{x:x>3\}$.)

Answer (score 1):

The mathematical OR is inclusive that mean $A\vee B$ is true if either $A$ or $B$ or both $A$ and $B$ are true.
The exclusive or has another notation. $A\underline V B$

Answer (score 0):

The issue you seem to be running into is that the "definition" of disjunction that you are using is inappropriate to the context in which you are using it. Despite how logic is often presented, there is not one universal definition of disjunction (or any of the other logical connectives). Instead, things like disjunction are defined implicitly by the logical framework within which you are working. Different logical frameworks lead to different definitions.

There are two broad approaches for defining logical frameworks: a syntactic approach and a semantic approach. In a syntactic approach, formulas are inert pieces of syntax - just symbols on a page - and we provide rules for manipulating those pieces of syntax. The behavior of disjunction is then implicitly defined by how it can be manipulated.

More relevant is the semantic approach. In this case, formulas are still just inert pieces of syntax, but now we provide a function to *interpret* those pieces of syntax as other mathematical objects. We then say that a formula is "true" if it is interpreted as one of some given mathematical objects. The meaning of disjunction is then determined by the interpretation function.

By far the most well-known semantics is truth tables which is a semantics for classical *propositional* logic. In this case, we interpret formulas of *propositional* logic as Boolean functions. A formula is "true" if the Boolean function it is interpreted as is a constant function with the value we arbitrarily decide to stand for "true".

The problem you are having is that you are not working in classical *propositional* logic: you are working in (presumably classical) *predicate* logic. In particular, the syntax of propositional logic does not include formulas with free variables or quantifiers. Truth table semantics simply does not apply to predicate logic. The most common semantics for classical *predicate* logic is to interpret predicates as subsets of a cartesian product of a given domain set, or equivalently, as relations on the given domain set. In this case, the interpretation of disjunction is the union of those relations which is just where you started.

You found the correct answer using one semantic approach to classical predicate logic in your first paragraph. In your second paragraph, you attempted to apply a semantics for classical propositional logic to your predicate logic formulas, and, unsurprisingly, this led to confusion.

Comment: Before reading your reply, I feel relaxed with the definition of union interpreted by disjunction, $ A \cap B = { x| (x \in A)  \vee (x \in B) }$ is fine to me. But I found the interpretation of disjunction is the union, I get confused, if the union is interpreted by disjunction,then the interpretation of disjunction of the union is then the disjunction itself.

Comment: @caozi Yep. The resolution is that there are *two* logics and thus two notions of disjunction. When we map a formula into a mathematical object via a semantics, what logical framework do we use to reason about these mathematical objects? We refer to that logical framework as the meta-logic. The meta-logic may be informal or we may formalize it (often using a syntactic approach). In this case, you can either use an informal, intuitive understanding of "union", or you can reduce that to an informal, intuitive understanding of disjunction which is unrelated to truth tables.

Comment: When I say, "either Sam or Max left," you don't use truth tables to figure out what I meant. You just understand. We can just say, "$x$ is in the union of $A$ and $B$ if $x$ is in $A$ or $x$ is in $B$". You don't need truth tables to understand this. In practice, most of mathematics is done at this informal level. When we do consider formal systems, a common arrangement is to discuss first-order theories semantically where the mathematical objects are the sets of ZFC set theory which is itself a first-order theory which we usually treat syntactically which itself is understood informally.

Comment: Only the formal rather than the intuitive makes me feel safe, isn't that what math is? Strip the intuitive, sometimes hard to conceive even ambiguous out of our incomplete perception of the world. The intuitive way sometimes may perform well because I practiced many times by which I came to gain the intuitive way. It's sometimes fast and precise,but I cannot use a formal sentence to reason the way I resolve. This is the core element that confuses me most. I guess I diverted from the original problem-solving purpose to the real confusion puzzled me for a very long time.

Comment: @caozi That math is all about formalism or formal arguments is a common misrepresentation, at least of mathematical practice. Math (in e.g. research papers) is rarely done formally. If you are interested in formalization, computer science and related mathematical fields are better places to look. Nevertheless, one can't escape informal reasoning. Even with a proof assistant like Coq, it requires informal reasoning to convince yourself that it is correctly implemented. Still, formalism can dramatically reduce our reliance on intuition, and it can definitely refine and correct our intuitions.

Comment: I came to the field of formalism when I got lost in how to define an event in the field of probability. I found myself lacking the ability to express the fact in the context and to formalize the event whose probability is to be calculated.

Answer (score 0):

Let me address the specific example you're asking about. One of the key properties of disjunction is that from $P\vee Q$ and $P\implies Q$ we can deduce $Q$. Formally, we prove this by cases: if $P\vee Q$ is true, then either $P$ is true - in which case $Q$ is also true since $P\implies Q$ - or $Q$ is true; either way, $Q$ is true.

In your example, $P$ is $x>10$ and $Q$ is $x>3$: the statement "$P\implies Q$" is clearly true, so we know that $P\vee Q$ implies $Q$. Meanwhile, obviously $Q$ implies $P\vee Q$. So $P\vee Q$ is equivalent to $Q$.

Notice that this patterns exactly the explanation of why $\{x:x>3\}\cup\{x:x>10\}=\{x:x>3\}$. So the parallel between disjunction and union continues to hold up. What we're seeing is that *set-theoretic rules* are paralleled by *logical rules*: the logical rule

- If $P\implies Q$ is true, then $P\vee Q$ is equivalent to $Q$

which we've used above is analogous to the set-theoretic rule

- If $A\subseteq B$, then $A\cup B=B$

which you've used in your question.

Answer (score 0):

I'll try to answer this just using the definition you quoted: A disjunction is true if and only if at least one of the disjuncts is true. What does this mean for the specific disjunction $(x>3)\lor(x>10)$? Well, since the formulas here compare $x$ to $3$ and to $10$, we have several cases to consider, according to where $x$ is located relative to $3$ and to $10$.

First case: $x$ is below both $3$ and $10$. In this case neither $(x>3)$ nor $(x>10)$ is true. Since neither disjunct is true, the disjunction is (according to the definition) not true. Notice that what I wrote about this case remains correct if $x=3$, so we don't have to treat that case separately.

Second case: $x$ is between $3$ and $10$. In this case, $(x>3)$ is true but $(x>10)$ is false. So exactly one of the two disjuncts is true. In particular, at least one disjunct is true, and so  the disjunction is true.  Notice that what I wrote about this case remains correct if $x=10$, so we don't have to treat that case separately.

Third case: $x$ is above $10$. Then both disjuncts $(x>3)$ and $(x>10)$ are true. Since two is at least one, we have that at least one disjunct is true, and therefore so is the disjunction.

Summary: The disjunction $(x>3)\lor(x>10)$ is true in the second and third cases and false in the first case.  In other words, this disjunction is true exactly when $x>3$ is true.  This means that the disjunction is *equivalent* to $x>3$.